# How to keep position of scrollbar with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scrollbar

There are a lot of pdf pages that is wrapped by div in a page. When they were zoomed by increasing div's width and height, scrollbar lose its position.

How can I fix it like **[this example](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html)**?

As you see in the example, when you zoom anywhere in the page, scrollbar didn't lose its position and it acts as a sticky.

What is your suggestion?